# request that a vote should be taken

Tags: subjunctives

*The deputies submitted a request that a vote should be taken.*

Is it possible to determine from the above sentence whether a noticed vote occured or not? I'm just guessing without any support that this sentence is related to the future (the fact of a voting) and that the one that tells the event happened would have this form: *The deputies submitted that a vote should have been taken*. Am I right or is it a nonsense and the sentence does not indicate the potential past or future of a vote?

Comment: If I **request** that you pay me a million dollars, what can you infer about whether I am now or soon to be a millionaire? You can infer that a request was made, but nothing about whether the request was fulfilled.

Comment: As an aside, it really ought to be "...submitted a request that a vote be taken" or else some variation on "...asserted that a vote should be taken."

Comment: No, we have no idea from the sentence alone whether a vote was actually taken. (Although, I don't know what you mean by a "noticed" vote.

Answer (score 1):

A request is a request.  The sentence is neutral on whether the request was fulfilled.

Incidentally, I consider *should* to be out of place in that sentence.

Corrected version:

> The deputies submitted a request that a vote be taken.

Example of correct use of *should*:

> The deputies voiced their opinion that a vote should be taken.

Usually, people prefer to avoid the subjunctive altogether:

> The deputies submitted a request for a vote.